# Multievaluated vertical arrow

Tags: vertical

I'm looking for a command of "multievaluated".
I've found something like `|_{i}^{j}` which kind of works for two limits.
However I rather N-multievaluated staff, i.e `|^{}_{}_{}...._{}`.
Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you give a pointer for a graphic realization of your wish?